# Magical Record object for current thread

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record 2.3.0 beta 5 and I have troubles understanding how to get my `NSManagedObject`s for the current thread. I have a long running `NSOperation` where I need my `PSPlayer` (`NSManagedObject`).

When I init the NSOperation, I keep an id of my `PSPlayer` and re-fetch the same object in the operation's `main` method. According [to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html) that the way to do it.

```
@implementation TAPlayerUpdateOperation 

- (instancetype)initWithPlayer:(PSPlayer *)player;
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.playerMD5Id = player.md5Id;
    }
}

- (void)main
{
    @autoreleasepool {

        __block BOOL keepUpdating = YES;
        PSPlayer *player = [[PSPlayer MR_findAllWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"md5Id == %@", self.playerMD5Id]] firstObject];
        NSLog(@"player.md5Id = %@", player.md5Id);
        // rest of my operation logic
    }
}
@end
```

When I run my app with `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`, I get a crash when accessing the property in the NSLog statement.

What is the correct way to get my `NSManagedObject` so that it is safe for the current thread?

I've pinned the problem down to the following snippet where it crashes as well.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    PSPlayer *player =[[PSPlayer MR_findAll] firstObject];
    NSLog(@"player = %@", player.name);
});
```

cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that everything is saved and merged before the fetch would work. If you're using MR then it's better to take the managed object and call `inContext:` on it supplying the other context and have it do the work (it also avoids a predicate).

I expect the crash is because you use `player.md5Id` instead of `self.playerMD5Id` so you're accessinh the managed object on the wrong thread.

Comment: if I want to use the `MR_inContext:`, where do I get the context to pass as argument from? I've updated my question with a simple snippet that reproduces the crash.